# Set a samesite cookie for an online shopping site

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, payment-gateway, samesite, cross-site

I have an online shopping site and I have to connect to the payment gateway to buy. Newer versions **of Chrome** have a **new policy**. That said, you should add an attribute called **sameSite** to your **cookies**. When I set-cookie attribute,  I add **sameSite = none** and **secure** to the cookie. Isn't this a problem in terms of **security**? Because I think our cookie is sent to **every site** and it is not secure.
Do you think there is a way to restrict the sending of cookies?
That is, for example, if we allow the user to send a cookie only for the payment gateway?

Comment: This question may be on-topic on https://security.stackexchange.com/